# Анимация кнопок

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qpushbutton, qparallelanimationgroup

Хочу сделать **`четыре`** (основные) кнопки, при нажатии будут выскакивать еще **`три`** (локальные) кнопки и двигать остальные основные кнопки снизу, а при нажатии на другую или ту, которая уже открыта, закрывать открыть кнопку и открыть на той, которую вы нажали, и так со всеми четырьмя кнопками.

Я пытался сделать со списками и изменить конфигурацию места. 
Вроде все работает, хоть и на костылях, но когда кнопка смещает другие кнопки, то в момент анимации появляются артефакты от контура нижних кнопок.

Может есть ссылка на гидхаб или кто-нибудь простой пример напишет?

И да, был бы благодарен если бы накинули сайт где раcписаны ВСЕ Классы/Методы/Эффекты/Анимации и вообще все фишки о *PyQt5*.

[image: Вот пример на Tkinter. Условно нажимая другую кнопку то если была открыта другая то закрыть её и открыть на ту которую нажал и сдвинуть остальные вниз. И да при анимации появляются жуткие артефакты]

Вот пример на *Tkinter*. Условно нажимая другую кнопку, то если была открыта другая, то закрыть её и открыть на ту которую нажал и сдвинуть остальные вниз. И да при анимации появляются жуткие артефакты

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Как прикрепить видео?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

То, что вы задумали, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CollapsibleBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super(CollapsibleBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text=title, checkable=True, checked=False
        )
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("""
            QToolButton { 
                border: 2px solid #09009B;
                border-radius: 4px;
                min-width:  145px;
                min-height:  30px;
            }
            QToolButton::checked { 
                border: 2px solid #ff009B;
            }    
        """)
        
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(
            QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon
        )
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)

        self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)

        self.content_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(
            maximumHeight=0, minimumHeight=0
        )
        self.content_area.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
        )
        self.content_area.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_area)

        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
        )
        self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
            QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.content_area, b"maximumHeight")
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pressed(self):
        checked = self.toggle_button.isChecked()
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
        )
        self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
            QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
            if not checked
            else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
        )
        self.toggle_animation.start()

    def setContentLayout(self, layout):
        lay = self.content_area.layout()
        del lay
        self.content_area.setLayout(layout)
        collapsed_height = (
            self.sizeHint().height() - self.content_area.maximumHeight()
        )
        content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
        for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
            animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
            animation.setDuration(500)
            animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
            animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

        content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(
            self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1
        )
        content_animation.setDuration(500)
        content_animation.setStartValue(0)
        content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(centralWidget) 
        
        _list = ['PREMINT', 'ALPHABOT', 'SUPERFULL', 'FREENFT',]
        
        for i, title in enumerate(_list):
            box = CollapsibleBox(title)
            vlay.addWidget(box)
            lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            lay.setSpacing(0)
            lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            for j in range(3):
                textButton = "Button {}-{}".format(i, j) 
                pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(textButton, 
                    clicked=lambda _, t=textButton: print(t))
                pushButton.setMaximumWidth(150)
                pushButton.setMinimumHeight(25)
                
                color = QtGui.QColor(*[random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3)])
                pushButton.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: {}; color : white;".format(color.name())
                )
                
                lay.addWidget(pushButton)
            box.setContentLayout(lay)
            
        vlay.addStretch()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вообще отлично, вот только как сделать чтобы к примеру: У меня открыт SUPERFULL после я открываю PREMINT и у меня SUPERFULL закрывается и так со всеми

Comment: @рома я рад что вам понравилось. Попробуйте реализовать то что написали выше самостоятельно, а если не получится - зададите новый вопрос и покажите, что вы пытались сделать. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @рома что не так?

Comment: Да не, я просто пока занят был, ответ поставил как верный. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @рома пожалуйста.

Comment: @S.Nick Здравствуйте, Мне очень понравилось ваше решение, оно идеально подходит для моего проекта, поэтому я сижу и разбираю его, в данный момент я не могу понять для чего нужен фрагмент кода где в CollapsibleBox вы в toggle_animation добавляете первые 2 анимации, без них тоже вроде хорошо работает. Так же в setContentLayout вы создаёте переменную lay с self.content_area.layout(), а затем удаляете её, почему так? Вы создаёте цикл и в нём устанавливаете настройки для animation, но и без этого цикла код отлично работает. Я только начал разбираться с анимациями, если не трудно, объясните =)

Comment: @PeFoo Здравствуйте. Если у вас есть какие-либо вопросы или проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приведите код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорощо расскажите что вы  хотите сделать и что у вас не получается или что вам не понятно.