# разворачивание и сворачивание groupbox pyside6

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6

можно ли как-то реализовать данную функцию, чтобы по нажатию groupbox разворачивался и назад

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

class SettingPage(QtWidgets.QWidget):

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = parent
    
    self.initialize()
    
def initialize(self):
    
    self.ui.toolButton.setStyleSheet("""
        QToolButton { 
            border: 2px solid #09009B;
            border-radius: 4px;
            min-width:  145px;
            min-height:  30px;
        }
        QToolButton::checked { 
            border: 2px solid #ff009B;
        }    
    """)
    
    self.ui.toolButton.setToolButtonStyle(
        QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon
    )
    
    self.ui.toolButton.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
    self.ui.toolButton.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)
    self.toggle_animation = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self)

    self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
        QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"minimumHeight")
    )
    self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
        QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"maximumHeight")
    )
    self.toggle_animation.addAnimation(
        QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.groupBox_12, b"maximumHeight")
    )
    
    self.ui.groupBox_12.setSizePolicy(
        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed
    )
    # self.ui.groupBox_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    self.setContentLayout(self.ui.groupBox_12, QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
    
    
@QtCore.Slot()
def on_pressed(self):
    checked = self.ui.toolButton.isChecked()
    self.ui.toolButton.setArrowType(
        QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if not checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow
    )
    self.toggle_animation.setDirection(
        QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward
        if not checked
        else QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward
    )
    self.toggle_animation.start()
    
    
    
    
def setContentLayout(self, area, layout):
    lay = area.layout()
    del lay
    area.setLayout(layout)
    collapsed_height = (
        self.sizeHint().height() + area.maximumHeight()
    )
    content_height = layout.sizeHint().height()
    for i in range(self.toggle_animation.animationCount()):
        animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(i)
        animation.setDuration(500)
        animation.setStartValue(collapsed_height)
        animation.setEndValue(collapsed_height + content_height)

    content_animation = self.toggle_animation.animationAt(
        self.toggle_animation.animationCount() - 1
    )
    content_animation.setDuration(500)
    content_animation.setStartValue(0)
    content_animation.setEndValue(content_height)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Артём, покажите что вы уже успели написать и лучше объясните что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: я пока ничего не написал, я просто где-то увидел, что так делали, но это был готовый результат. что хочу сделать, хочу сделать, как вот на картинке, чтобы при загрузки, например, фрейма было много таких пунктов свернутых. но главное то, чтобы они поддерживали такую же функцию, как на фото, то есть, на них можно нажать и соответственно они раскроются и в них будет какой-то контент, кнопки, поля, что угодно, то есть он станет обвчным groupbox. но если снова нажать на него, то он бы свернулся в первоначальне состояние, как вот на фото, те пункты, что ниже

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1497920/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba/1497999#1497999

Comment: а не подскажите, как вот можно исправить данный вывод groupbox? а то я пробую по ссылке, которую вы дали, но что-то идёт не так, весь дизайн делаю в qt designer

Comment: Артём, sorry, чтобы дать вам какие-либо советы, нужен  [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Я вам привел одну ссылку на похожий вопрос, а если вы еще покопаетесь на этом ресурсе, то еще найдете ряд вопросов с такой анимацией. Вы пишите, что весь дизайн делаете в Qt Designer, это вы к чему написали и почему вы так делаете? В  Qt Designer, анимацию написать не возможно.

Comment: просто вы создаёте элементы так вот, во время работы программы через код, а я должен сделать условную заготовку в qt designer и её уже ворошить, я попробовал вставить так groupbox, но почему-то он не раскрывается полностью, весь код, который я предоставил, он является полным, я добавил скриншот, как выглядит проблема, простите

Comment: Артём, ваш пример НЕ является полным. Воспроизводимый приме, это когда я скопирую ваш пример и запущу у себя, он запустится и покажет проблему , о которой вы должны хорошо рассказать.

Comment: понял, простите пожалуйста, не смею вас больше тревожить